# How to change the element value in json format

Tags: python, json

I'd like to change the delivery window value.
Here is the original data structure.

```
{
   "locations":[
      {
         "depot_duration_s":90,
         "depot_id":"depot_1",
         "time_window":"09:00-20:00",
         "type":"delivery"
      },
      {
         "depot_duration_s":90,
         "depot_id":"depot_1",
         "time_window":"09:00-20:00",
         "type":"delivery"
      },
      {
         "depot_duration_s":90,
         "depot_id":"depot_1",
         "time_window":"09:00-20:00",
         "type":"delivery"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the code I tried, but I got "list indices must be integers or slices, not str".
Could you let me know how to fix the code here?

```
import json

with open('C:/Users/8_31_file.json', 'r+', errors = "ignore") as myData:
    myData = json.load(myData)
    mylist = myData["locations"][-2:]
    mylist["time_window"] = "17:00-20:00"
    mylist = {'locations':mylist}
    print(mylist)
```

Comment: Do you want to change the value of all in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `mylist` to be a `list` object. You then try to call `mylist["time_window"]` which is where the error is coming from. As the error says the index of a list cannot be a `str`. You probably want something like:

`mylist[0]["time_window"] = "17:00-20:00"`

You need to know which element of `mylist` to change though. If you are trying to change all elements then you would need to iterate over `mylist` like this:

```
for i in mylist:
    i['time_window'] = "17:00-20:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on @abinitio's answer, you can even simplify your whole logic into this:

```
with open('C:/Users/8_31_file.json', 'r+', errors = "ignore") as myData:
    myData = json.load(myData)
    for loc in myData["locations"]:
        loc["time_window"] = "17:00-20:00"
    print(myData)
```